# Java - What happens with this part of code?

Tags: java, math, divide

I am currently watching some tutorials and I am stuck at a part that looks like this:

```
int x = (int) a_float / an_int;
```

What will happed if a_float /  an_int; is not an integer? Will the number be rounded / floored / weird stuff?

Comment: yes it will be rounded to int before performing the division

Comment: What happened when you tried this code out yourself?

Comment: Why didn't you just perform a test case?

Comment: @Ashish Incorrect; floats coerced to ints are truncated, not rounded.

Comment: truncated? what does that mean? the decimal digits get cut off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, casting takes precedence over division: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/. This means that the statement can be broken down as follows:

1. Truncate `a_float` (basically take the floor and store as an `int`)
2. Do integer division by `an_int`
3. Assign the resulting `int` value to `x`

If you want `an_int` to be promoted to a `float` before the operation, then do the division, omit the cast. The result will be a `float` (which you can than truncate back into an `int` before assignment):

```
int x = (float)(a_float / an_int);
```

is the same as

```
int x = (float)(a_float / (float)an_int);
```

You can also read this site for a pretty good explanation of what it all means: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html